# Firestore where clause doesn't make the condition.

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

in my function I have two where clauses. what I want is to check whether a document exits, where two ids are found. but when I run it, it returns all the records of collection. can anybody tell me where I messed up?

```
setApplyStatus() {
   var query = firebase.firestore().collection('applications')
   query.where("jobSeekerId", '==', this.jobSeekerId).get()
   query.where("jobId", '==', this.job.id)
   query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
     console.log(doc.data())
     console.log('already exists')
     this.applyStatus = true
    })
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not chaining the query clauses correctly.  Also, you're calling get() in the middle of your chain.  That's almost certainly not what you want.  Each query object builds on the last, and you should only get() on the final query in the chain:

```
setApplyStatus() {
  var query = firebase.firestore().collection('applications')
    .where("jobSeekerId", '==', this.jobSeekerId)
    .where("jobId", '==', this.job.id)
    .get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
      console.log('already exists')
      this.applyStatus = true
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For new users, who are watching this in 2021. the code is next:
PS. there is no more "==" clause, it's now 'isEqualTo: parameter'

```
void setApplyStatus() {
    var query = firebase.firestore().collection('applications');
    query = query.where("jobSeekerId", isEqualTo: this.jobSeekerId)
    query = query.where("jobId", isEqualTo: this.job.id)
    query = query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
         querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
         console.log(doc.data())
         console.log('already exists')
         this.applyStatus = true
         })
       })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try making an index at firebase for your query since without the index it will fail to bring out your result. You can get the link to make the index at the console in an error so check your console

Answer (score 0):

```
setApplyStatus() {
  var query = firebase.firestore().collection('applications')
  query = query.where("jobSeekerId", '==', this.jobSeekerId)
  query = query.where("jobId", '==', this.job.id)
  query = query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
     console.log(doc.data())
     console.log('already exists')
     this.applyStatus = true
    })
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA", "||", "state", "==", "AZ")

or better yet

citiesRef.where("state == CA || state == AZ") Source: Firebase GIT